# Boot Error -> ipmi:dmi : Invalid offset : 0

Tags: kernel, boot, linux-kernel, ssd, trim

I'm having the following error when booting my OS (Linux mint19 - mate):

```
ipmi:dmi: Invalid offset : 0
```

I would appreciate if someone has more information about this.

There's a ubuntu user here on this forum struggling with this error when he was installing the OS, but I'm having this error during the boot.

Also, this error is reproducible for me. It appears everytime I hibernate and shut down after that. So I guess that could be something related to hibernation or the grub.

Googling, I found some users saying that is related do SSD Trim and you must disable this feature to avoid the error, but I don't have a SSD here (running on my laptop HD).

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely **kernel**-related. So that, even kernels provided in the iso by the distribution officially may cause this (in my case it was 4.13 with all *buntus I tried that day, though it was the official in the iso).

So, just try newer kernels or older but particularly "Long Term Maintenance" ones, best..

For today, kernel 4.9.xxx seems to solve the issue. Please also see :

https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?f=104&t=51644

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you got it, but I will post here anyway to help me on the future. I dont have a good memory soo... xD

In my case this issue happens because, I have two disks; the one first is SSD with my ext4 and swap. And second is a HD with windows.

Also, in this HD I have one partition just for files and bkp, that I use it with linux and windows too. Then this error happens with me, always when I need to use windows (in rare cases) and a write(save a file) in this shared partition.

To make things easy to me, I fixed as auto on my /etc/fstab to every time that I start my linux partition this shared partition mount together it.

for this reason the error appears to me:

```
ipmi:dmi: Invalid offset : 0
```

Then, to solve it:
After comment the automount on fstab, I just open the terminal(LIVE USB) and do the unmount partition on my ext4, and then:

```
fsck -nf /dev/<partition>
```

And as a bonus:

If you is like me, you will need to fix the ntfs partition to get it mounted on linux again:

```
sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/<ntfs partition>
```

is it.

good vibes!