# How do I tell the linux kernel that I don't have IPMI?

Tags: linux-kernel, boot, kernel-modules, kernel-parameters, ipmi

I'm trying to clean up known or bogus error messages that shows up in the log when I boot my Debian server, in order to more clearly see actual errors. Now it's come to this:

```
Base address is zero, assuming no IPMI interface
```

Since I know that my system ([Supermicro H8SGL](https://www.supermicro.com/Aplus/motherboard/Opteron6000/SR56x0/H8SGL.cfm)) does *not* have IPMI (gotta pay extra - I didn't) it appears that the vendor sets the base address to zero to mark a non-existing feature, something that the kernel frowns upon according to the [kernel patch](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/1574608f5f4204440d6d9f52b971aba967664764) introducing the message. From the changelog:

> **ipmi:dmi: Ignore IPMI SMBIOS entries with a zero base address**
>
> Looking at logs from systems all over the place, it looks like tons of broken systems exist that set the base address to zero.  I can only guess that is some sort of non-standard idea to mark the interface as not being present.  It can't be zero, anyway, so just complain and ignore it.

Can I tell the kernel at boot with some kind of flag that I don't even want it to try doing whatever it does in order to end up with this error? I'm not sure if this is a module that is being autoloaded, something built in to the kernel, or something else...

There is a possibly-relevant question here at U&L, [Boot Error -> ipmi:dmi : Invalid offset : 0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470359/boot-error-ipmidmi-invalid-offset-0) but the answer is basically "just try newer kernels" and a bunch of people in forums who thinks it relates to Windows and SSDs, so it is not very helpful.